# How to change to some directory and do operations in it using Ammonite Ops?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am playing with Ammonite ops, and would like to automate doing 'git pull' on a couple of git repos. I am unable to figure out how to change to that particular directory (where I want to do a git pull) because the docs say that -

> there are no in-built operations to change the `cwd`. In general you should not need to: simply defining a new path, e.g. val target = cwd/'target Should be sufficient for most needs.

Although the solution too is mentioned above, but I have not been able to achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an implicit Path variable, and that variable will be used as the current directory.

Example:

```
implicit val currentDir = home/'mydir
```

and this directory will be used for future `%` and `%%` invocations.
Alternatively, you can supply the current dir in each invocation.